# Contact.php Form Issue

Tags: php, contacts, contact-form

Having trouble with my contact.php form. It seems to be working intermittently and can't spot what I am doing wrong.

Hosting is with GoDaddy and they said to add the following but not sure where relay-hosting.secureserver.net

Any help or references to building one of these would be very helpful. Current code is below.

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "info@resonatebusiness.com";
$email_subject = "NEW WEBSITE INQUIRY";


$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($full_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($message)."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
  header("Location: http://www.publishingpush.com");
  exit;
  ?>
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Does it throw any errors? Does it not submit? Is information missing upon submission? Please be more clear

Comment: What indication do you have that it doesn't work?  Also, for starters, you're suppressing errors on the call to `mail()` so there could very well be a reason why the mail fails to send, you're just ignoring that reason.

Comment: A fair amount of people have said that GoDaddy doesn't allow people to send e-mails. Maybe start looking at a PHP plugin?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. It does submit and gets to the end of the form as it re-directs to the page www.publishingpush.com

Its just that the emails arent coming through to the email info@resonatebusiness.com

Comment: Have you tried turning off error suppression (remove the `@`) from the `mail()` call to see if it throwing any errors?

Comment: @PatGW: `"the emails arent coming through"` - That doesn't necessarily mean anything is wrong with the code.  Emails can fail to show up in your inbox for any number of reasons.  Is the SMTP server rejecting the message?  Is the receiving mail server rejecting the message?  Is the mail client filtering the message as potential junk?  Is anything bouncing back to the `$email_from` address?  Anything could go wrong.  At the very least, don't suppress errors from the SMTP server.  It could be actively *telling you* what the error is.

Comment: Not getting any errors its redirecting fine. Bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting your form before the mail is sent. Redirect only after successful mail function execution.

```
if( mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers) ){
 //redirect
}
```

Comment: Hi Ankit I added that and it is still redirecting but email not coming through still

Comment: Did you checked your spam folder?

Comment: Have fixed this now but thanks for you help @console

Answer (score 0):

try the below code and see first if the server is properly trapping the information and sending it to your e-mail -

p.s. change the location of your **thankyou.html** redirect page to whatever is your redirect landing page post form submit. 
*If this works*, just tweak the php to filter and pre-qualify the information  you need.

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = 'info@resonatebusiness.com'; 

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['full_name']);
$lname = check_input($_POST['last_name']);
$email = check_input($_POST['email']);
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject']);
$spec_message = check_input($_POST['message']); 


/*E-mail Subject */
$subject = 'NEW WEBSITE INQUIRY' ;

/*From Address */
$headers = "From: $name $lname";

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "
Name: $name, $lname
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject
Message: $spec_message
" ;

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit();

?>
```